# What does exportClasses actually do with S4 classes?

Tags: r, r-s4

I was trying to understand how namespacing works with S4 classes so put a small example together using different export directives. The results make no sense to me so was hoping someone might be able to help explain what's going on ?

My package consists of just 1 file with the following code:

```
B1 <- setClass( "Base_1", slots = list(x = "numeric"))
B2 <- setClass( "Base_2", slots = list(x = "numeric"))
B3 <- setClass( "Base_3", slots = list(x = "numeric"))
B4 <- setClass( "Base_4", slots = list(x = "numeric"))
```

I then define the following in the NAMESPACE file:

```
export(B1)
exportClasses(Base_1)
export(B2)
exportClasses(Base_3)
```

I then load and try to use the package as follows:

```
library(tstpkg)

B1(x = 1)   # Runs fine
B2(x = 1)   # Runs fine
B3(x = 1)   # Errors (as expected)
B4(x = 1)   # Errors (as expected)

new("Base_1", x = 1)   # Runs fine
new("Base_2", x = 1)   # Runs fine - Was expecting to error
new("Base_3", x = 1)   # Runs fine
new("Base_4", x = 1)   # Runs fine - Was expecting to error

setClass("Derv_1", contains = "Base_1")   # Runs fine
setClass("Derv_2", contains = "Base_2")   # Runs fine - Was expecting to error
setClass("Derv_3", contains = "Base_3")   # Runs fine
setClass("Derv_4", contains = "Base_4")   # Runs fine - Was expecting to error
```

I was expecting `new(<class>)` and `setClass(..., contains=<class>)` to fail for `Base_2` and `Base_4` as neither of these classes were exposed. Any one able to explain what's happening here ?

(I put all code into a github repo [here](https://github.com/gowerc/S4NS) if you want to play with the code yourselves)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes that you export are placed in a list of exports, stored in your package namespace.  Here is a list of classes exported by package **Matrix**, version 1.6-0:

```r
ns <- asNamespace("Matrix")
ns.exports <- getNamespaceInfo(ns, "exports")
cl1 <- sort(grep("^[.]__C__", names(ns.exports), value = TRUE))
cl1[1:20]
```

```
 [1] ".__C__BunchKaufman"              ".__C__BunchKaufmanFactorization"
 [3] ".__C__CHMfactor"                 ".__C__CHMsimpl"                 
 [5] ".__C__CHMsuper"                  ".__C__Cholesky"                 
 [7] ".__C__CholeskyFactorization"     ".__C__CsparseMatrix"            
 [9] ".__C__LU"                        ".__C__Matrix"                   
[11] ".__C__MatrixFactorization"       ".__C__QR"                       
[13] ".__C__RsparseMatrix"             ".__C__Schur"                    
[15] ".__C__SchurFactorization"        ".__C__TsparseMatrix"            
[17] ".__C__abIndex"                   ".__C__atomicVector"             
[19] ".__C__compMatrix"                ".__C__corMatrix"
```

Here is a list of classes defined in the **Matrix** namespace but *not* exported:

```r
cl0 <- setdiff(sort(grep("^[.]__C__", names(ns), value = TRUE)), cl1)
cl0
```

```
 [1] ".__C__dCsparseMatrix" ".__C__determinant"    ".__C__geMatrix"      
 [4] ".__C__lCsparseMatrix" ".__C__mMatrix"        ".__C__nCsparseMatrix"
 [7] ".__C__numLike"        ".__C__replValueSp"    ".__C__seqMat"        
[10] ".__C__xMatrix"
```

Packages export classes in order to define what *other* packages can and cannot import.  If another package tries to import a class not exported from your package, then installation of that package will fail inside of a call to `importIntoEnv`, with an error of the form:

> class %s is not exported by 'namespace:%s'

Packages that import classes from other packages cache the definitions of the imported classes in the parent environment of their namespace.  They can also cache *superclass* definitions, but in the namespace itself, not its parent.  The latter cache is unknown to most S4-using package maintainers and is liable to become stale; I explain below.

Here is a list of classes exported by **Matrix**, version 1.6-0, and imported by **SeuratObject**, version 4.1.3:

```r
ns <- asNamespace("SeuratObject")
ns.imports <- getNamespaceInfo(ns, "imports")
ns.imports.Matrix <- c(ns.imports[names(ns.imports) == "Matrix"],
                       recursive = TRUE, use.names = FALSE)
cl1 <- sort(grep("^[.]__C__", ns.imports.Matrix, value = TRUE))
```

```
[1] ".__C__dgCMatrix"
```

Just one, conveniently.  Here is the cached class definition:

```r
cl1.def <- mget(cl1, parent.env(ns))
str(cl1.def, max.level = 3L)
```

```
List of 1
 $ .__C__dgCMatrix:Formal class 'classRepresentation' [package "methods"] with 11 slots
  .. ..@ slots     :List of 6
  .. ..@ contains  :List of 11
  .. ..@ virtual   : logi FALSE
  .. ..@ prototype :Formal class 'S4' [package ""] with 0 slots
 list()
  .. ..@ validity  :function (object)  
  .. ..@ access    : list()
  .. ..@ className : chr "dgCMatrix"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "package")= chr "Matrix"
  .. ..@ package   : chr "Matrix"
  .. ..@ subclasses: list()
  .. ..@ versionKey:<externalptr> 
  .. ..@ sealed    : logi FALSE
```

And here are the cached superclass definitions:

```r
scl1 <- paste0(".__C__", sort(names(cl1.def[[1L]]@contains)))
scl1.def <- mget(scl1, ns, ifnotfound = list(NULL)) # NULL <=> unexported
str(scl1.def, max.level = 2L)
```

```
List of 11
 $ .__C__CsparseMatrix :Formal class 'classRepresentation' [package "methods"] with 11 slots
 $ .__C__Matrix        :Formal class 'classRepresentation' [package "methods"] with 11 slots
 $ .__C__compMatrix    :Formal class 'classRepresentation' [package "methods"] with 11 slots
 $ .__C__dCsparseMatrix: NULL
 $ .__C__dMatrix       :Formal class 'classRepresentation' [package "methods"] with 11 slots
 $ .__C__dsparseMatrix :Formal class 'classRepresentation' [package "methods"] with 11 slots
 $ .__C__generalMatrix :Formal class 'classRepresentation' [package "methods"] with 11 slots
 $ .__C__mMatrix       : NULL
 $ .__C__replValueSp   : NULL
 $ .__C__sparseMatrix  :Formal class 'classRepresentation' [package "methods"] with 11 slots
 $ .__C__xMatrix       : NULL
```

The caching of superclass definitions here points to a bug in **SeuratObject**: it imports `dgCMatrix` but none of its exported superclasses, i.e., it's `NAMESPACE` has

```r
importClassesFrom(Matrix, dgCMatrix)
```

but should really have

```r
importClassesFrom(Matrix, dgCMatrix,
                  ## and the exported superclasses:
                  CsparseMatrix, Matrix, compMatrix, dMatrix, 
                  dsparseMatrix, generalMatrix, sparseMatrix)
```

A consequence is that the superclass definitions cached in the namespace can eventually become stale.  Whereas the definition of `dgCMatrix` is retrieved at *load* time (when the parent environment of the namespace is populated), the definitions of the superclasses are retrieved at *install* time (when the namespace itself is populated [and serialized]).  If the **Matrix** version available at load time differs from the one available at install time, and if those versions contain conflicting superclass definitions, then users of **SeuratObject** can run into problems - ones that are quite hard to debug if you are not already familiar with the caching mechanism.

It probably should be documented in the Writing R Extensions manual ([here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/doc/manual/R-exts.html#Namespaces-with-S4-classes-and-methods)) that if you use some class, then you also implicitly use its superclasses and must import those, too.

These pitfalls are just one of many reasons why maintainers should try to preserve backwards compatibility when changing the definitions of classes that they export.

Finally, why do `new` and `setClass` "see" unexported classes?  In the case of `new`, I imagine that part of the reason is performance.  Instantiation must be fast, and the test for "exportedness" has a nontrivial cost.  In the case of `setClass`, I'm not so sure.  That definitely *seems* like a bug, but I'd want to think a bit harder about it, and maybe even consult the R-devel mailing list (also about amending WRE) ... [which I've now done](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2023-July/082739.html).

Comment: Did you get any follow up on whether `new` / `setClass` being able to access the non-exported classes was a bug or not ?

Comment: I did not end up consulting R-devel on that specific issue, as I convinced myself that the current behaviour is not really a bug.  Users have always been able to access unexported objects via `:::` and `get(., asNamespace(.))` (if trying to fool CRAN), and package maintainers have always been responsible for not shooting themselves in the foot.  Having said that, maybe a more reasonable proposal would be for `R CMD check` to test if the package makes use of classes not imported (and not already defined in package **methods**), as classes not exported can never be imported.